# How to delete a particular row from database when its corresponding delete link is clicked in magento?

Tags: magento

I displayed a table from database and created a delete link to every row. I want to delete a particular row when its corresponding link is clicked. Can anyone help me please..

```
    foreach($model as $obj)
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$obj->getTestId().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$obj->getTitle().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$obj->getFilename().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$obj->getContent().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$obj->getStatus().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$obj->getCreatedTime().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$obj->getUpdateTime().'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="#">'.'delete'.'</a></td>';
```

Comment: this is your custom model, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add this line inside the loop and replace modulefrontname with your frontname and replace controllername with your controller.

Add the deleteRowAction in your controller where you want to redirect when you click delete link.

```
<a href="<?php Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>modulefrontname/controllername/deleterow/<?php echo $obj->getTestId(); ?>">Delete</a>

public function deleteRowAction(){
                try{
                                $model = Mage::getModel("practice/practice");
                                $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))->delete();
                }catch(Exception $e){
                        Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                }
                //then redirect corresponds url
    }
```